# How to change a server variable on behalf of the client (unity mirror)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I made this shooting code via raycast

```
void Shoot()
{
    if (isServer)
    {
        s_Shoot();
    }
    else
    {
        c_Shoot();
    }
}

[Server]
void s_Shoot()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Physics.Raycast(FPScam.transform.position, FPScam.transform.forward, out hit);

    if (hit.transform.name.Contains("Player"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit");
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().HP);
        hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().HP -= damage;
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().HP);
    }
}

[Command]
void c_Shoot()
{
    s_Shoot();
}
```

Logically, on the client side, we ask the server to shoot from the camera, which is synchronized between the client and the server, and if we hit an object that has the word Player in its name, we write hit in the console, the initial health value,
then in the health script that the player has in the HP variable, we remove health to the damage value and write a new health value, HP has syncvar, but only the host can remove health (although from the debug you can understand that everything except just changing the variable works) , and neither a client to a host nor a client to another client can cause damage

P.S. here is the health code (death is a function that will work if hp is less than 100, for now it just writes “death” to the console)

```
[SyncVar]
public int HP = 100;

void Update()
{
    if (HP <= 0)
    {
        death();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a mirror expert .. do you not have a certain prefix to your RPC methods? In most Unity close networking I have always seen that methods needed to be called e.g. `Rpc...` or even more specific `ClientRpc...` / `ServerRpc...` could this be the case? I would try and add more logs to the methods and check on which device they are logged

Comment: I’m also not very experienced in mirror, but as I know, rpc is required so that the server can give commands to clients, but for now I need the opposite - to give a command from the client to the server to change a variable, correct me if I'm wrong, the problem is that many guides are already outdated and it is difficult to understand what is relevant and what is not

Comment: you dont seem to have said what the problem is - under [Command] this runs at server level, and then usually you call clients to do things, but you can put your own code in for the server by simply it not being a clientrpc call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a certain answer, but since it has been 20 days, I figured I would throw out a lifeline. I would guess that your problem most likely lays in the damage variable. If you change the damage variable on the client's end, the server will not see that change. Check to make sure your damage is not set to 0 when you call the function, if you have not found the issue already.

If I am correct, you can easily fix this. One way you can fix this is by passing in a parameter into the s_Shoot function (which would look like `s_Shoot(float damage)`), which means that the client can tell the server how much damage to apply. The only downside to this method is that the client can tell the server to apply *any* amount of damage to the target, which means that hackers could one-shot any enemy with any gun in game. A more secure method would be to calculate the damage on the server's end, but the implementation of that would vary depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: incredible but... IT DAMN WORKED! THANKS DUDE! HEALTH AND LUCK TO YOU! I WAS ALREADY THINKING OF FROZING THE PROJECT